Minimum singular value of a strictly lower triangular matrix of 1s
I am trying to find the smallest singular value for a strictly lower triangular matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times(n-1)}$ s.t.
$$
m_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, &i > j\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\quad \text{or,} \quad 
M = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & 0 \\
1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let us use $\sigma_{\text{min}}(n)$ to denote this smallest singular value of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times (n-1)}$. I ran some numerical simulations and discovered that $\sigma_{\text{min}}(n)$ is a decreasing function and has a limit
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sigma_{\text{min}}(n) = 1/2.
$$
Can anyone point out how I can theoretically derive a lower bound for the smallest singular value of this matrix $M$?
Thanks!

It is more convenient to adopt the convention that $M$ is $(n+1)\times n$ (rather than $n\times(n-1)$). With this convention, the singular values of $M$ are known to be $\frac12\sin\left(\frac{2j-1}{2n+1}\frac\pi2\right)^{-1}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Hence $\sigma_\min(M)=\frac12\sin\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\frac\pi2\right)^{-1}$, which decreases to $\frac12$ as $n\to\infty$.

Just what I needed. Thank you for the reference and the link!
